# Не входит в BIOS после установки Linux

Tags: linux, grub, archlinux, bios

После установки linux (ubuntu/garuda) не входит в bios т.е при запуске при нажатии f2 вместо биоса вылазит чёрный экран с полоской в верхнем левом углу

Ранее эту проблему я "решил" изменив место установки загрузчика на флешку после чего bios прекрасно открывался
И не важно стоит ли на этом диске windows или же это чистая установка linux но после обновления линукса он отказался запускаться таким образом

Хотелось бы узнать можно ли решить проблему без таких костылей

Сохранив возможность входа в биос и сам загрузчик линукса (на данный момент стоит Garuda)

Как я понимаю загрузчик линукса каким-то образом перекрывает bios т.к удаление раздела с загрузчиком возвращяет возможность использования bios

Comment: [Чтобы выполнить вход в БИОС на этом устройстве, при его активации или повторном перезапуске сразу же жмите клавишу «F2». Рекомендуется «щелкать» эту кнопку постоянно, чтобы не пропустить момент входа в БИОС.](https://radiosit.ru/os/acer-swift-3-zagruzka-s-fleshki.html)

Answer (score 1):

Точно Bios или все-таки UEFI? ПК или ноутбук?

Попробуй посмотреть этот топик: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/15751817

Вот один из вариантов

> Берешь liveCD с windows(я использовав Hiren) Жмешь на все F[1-12]
> чтобы найти boot-меню(у меня кажется F9 было или F12) накатываешь туда
> дрова ACPI чтобы у тебя нормально определялась зарядка ноута, иначе он
> может думать, что батарея разряжена, с разряженной батареей BIOS не
> обновится Дальше берешь отсюда утилиту для обновления BIOS
> https://www.samsung.com/ru/support/model/NP300E5X-A01RU/ и надеешься
> что у тебя уже не последняя версия(если сам не обновлял, то точно не
> она), она выгрузит обновления и накатит их идешь в настройки и
> вырубаешь UEFI к чертям, потому что в моделях NP300E5X он сломан и его
> так и не починили.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Ноутбук (acer swift SF314-52) а по поводу обновления bios'a так он увы последний стоит

Comment: Сейчас я спокойно могу запустить и установленый виндовс 11 но стоит только накатить linux и его загрузчик каким-то образом будто "перекрывает" bios т.к после удаления раздела с линуксовым загрузчиком биос открываеться спокойно (Снятие флага "boot" с раздела grub'a не изменило ситуацию)

Comment: Попробуйте в загруженной системе Ctrl + Alt +F3 , логинитесь в tty и пишете systemctl reboot –firmware-setup.

Comment: Отсылает к тому же чёрному экрану с полоской